# How do I get rid of a null app

Tags: ios, applications

I have a null app which is quite annoying, I’ve searched up how to delete it but they all say go to storage and delete it from their but the app isn’t in storage and I haven’t found a way to delete it

iPhone SE iOS 12.0.1

Comment: Where exactly do you see this app?

Comment: Just on the home screen it has the name but has no thumbnail and i can’t find it in storage but in App Store it says that I still have the app downloaded

Comment: find its PID in the Activity Monitor, the use `rm` in terminal